How to Integrate Next.js App Router and Contentful for my project
According to this link Contentful (headless CMS), how to set Preview URL and integrate my project with contentful and Nextjs.
PS. i have all the coding part in the article , which is same. if the content type and fields are given correctly, I should have seen output in local host but this one has preview URL to view our fields.
i have attached another post for my another project which has the same issue .  (previous post)
If anyone who have experience using Headless CMS , please answer this question. Thanks in  advance !!
